# Twig date formatting

Tags: symfony, date, twig

I'm trying to format a date and place each item (month, day and year) inside a div or span. I'm using a SaaS platform which provide a date like so:

```
2015-03-07 22:54:00
```

What I try to do is format this date into 3 separate items and place them in a div like so:

```
<span class="day">07</span>
<span class="month">March</span>
<span class="year">2015</span>
```

Therefore I need to strip everything behind a `-` and call it inside a div like so:

```
<span class="day">{{ article.date | split('-')[2] }}</span>
<span class="month">{{ article.date | split('-')[1] }}</span>
<span class="year">{{ article.date | split('-')[0] }}</span>
```

This gives me an output like:

```
<span class="day">07 22:54:00</span>
<span class="month">03</span>
<span class="year">2015</span>
```

Where I get stuck is to remove the time after the day and change the month into a textual representation.

I know it can be done with PHP date functions but I can't get that to work. The problem I'm facing is that the date needs to be stripped after each `-`.

Is there anybody who can help me with that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`date()`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html) function, and then the [`date`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) filter

**NB: they are 2 really different things!!!**

```
{% set dateTime = date(article.date) %}
<span class="day">{{ dateTime | date('d') }}</span>
<span class="month">{{ dateTime | date('F') }}</span>
<span class="year">{{ dateTime | date('Y') }}</span>
```

First, the `date()` function converts your string dates to a DateTime object.

Then, the `date` filter makes you do the equivalent of the [`DateTime::format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) PHP function, so you can use a separate notation for the desidered output.

If you need to translate the name of the month to a locale, you can pipe the `trans` filter, but it must be enabled first.

Comment: You don't need to use the `date()` function. You can just use the `date` filter with a string to cast to a \DateTime object and format like `article.date|date('d')` or `"now"|date('d')`.